# Error in React Native navigation ( createnativeStackNavigator )

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { PaperWrapper } from './src/PaperWrapper';
import {Provider as PaperProvider, MD3LightTheme as DefaultTheme} from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
import themeJson from './src/theme.json'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const theme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    colors: themeJson
 };

  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name='PaperWrapper' component={PaperWrapper}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

PaperWrapper.js

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'

const PaperWrapper = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
   <SafeAreaProvider >
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <SignUp/>
     </View>
   </SafeAreaProvider>
  )
}

export default PaperWrapper;
```

I have expo managed project. I referred [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) and want to include navigation in my project. The **SignUp** component is custom component defined, similar to the **PaperWrapper**. Only has forms inside it. I am getting this error only after I wrapped App.js with Navigation.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's an `export default`, update the way you import `PaperWrapper`:

From:

```js
import { PaperWrapper } from './src/PaperWrapper';
```

To:

```js
import PaperWrapper from './src/PaperWrapper';
```

**Update**

Also, change this:

```js
import {Provider as PaperProvider, MD3LightTheme as DefaultTheme} from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
```

By this:

```js
import {Provider as PaperProvider, MD3LightTheme as DefaultTheme} from "react-native-paper"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I just tried it. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Looks like you messed up your imports